# Spartacus B2C Login: "Register" Button missing after upgrade from 2.1 to 3.1

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I was trying to upgrade from B2C Spartacus 2.1 to 3.1.
Most of the workflows seem to work fine, like product search, add to cart, display PDP, wish list, etc.

[Attached Image - Register Button missing in Login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFpcN.png)

Somehow, the "Register" button of the login page is missing.
Do you have any pointers for me? Is this something related to the following issues?

- https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/7785
- https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/8022

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether `ReturningCustomerRegisterComponent` is missing from the slot `LeftContentSlot-login`. Without this CMS component, the `register` button will not be shown.

Comment: Hi Weizheng, Thanks for your resonse. Btw it was "RegisterCustomerComponent" in spartacus 2.1. So it has been named as "ReturningCustomerRegisterComponent" in spartacus 3.0?

Comment: But the commerce backend is same, that is 2011.

Comment: RegisterCustomerComponent is the component in the register page (register form); and ReturningCustomerRegisterComponent is the register button in login page. They are different.